# Download CSV generated client-side

Tags: html, http, dom

I'd like to provide a download link for a CSV that I've generated in Javascript in the browser. Data URI's are an obvious choice, but they don't work in IE for CSV.

#### Question #1: is there any cross-browser way to do this completely client-side?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. The next approach would be to generate a link, something like `/data_download?data=...`, and have a corresponding server-side resource that just responds with the contents of the `data` field from the querystring. The problem now seems to be that IE's max URL length is something around 2 KB, and I don't want to build that limit into my system.

So I made a server-side resource such that I can POST to `/data_download` with form data where the 'data' attribute is the CSV contents, and it responds with the form's 'data' field. This seems to work, but it's a pain b/c I need to have a `<form>` in the client-side markup, and even though I set the `mimetype` correctly, I get warnings in the browser that make me think this is going to break in some browsers:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "http://localhost:8001/data_download"

#### Question #2: is there a better way do do this that has some or all of the following characteristics:

- stateless: I'm not goint to create tokens on the server or anything that requires storing state between requests
- uses a GET request: so that I can just have a `<link>` tag instead of an entire `<form>`

Comment: Your warning might be because data_download does not set the right Content-Type header.

Comment: good thinking, but yes, i'm specifying the Content-Type header correctly in data_download. i'll update the question.

Comment: Make a server-side proxy and send the data via POST, not GET.

Comment: I'm getting this same warning but only in chrome. Do you set cacheability anywhere? I read that might be connected (I set the page the CSV page is called from to not cache)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2013/05/stupid-download-of-browser-self.html
The data-uri with filename (download attribute of anchor element) is supporte by FF20+ and Chrome.

You can make it work completely client-side in IE in a way though:

```
if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent) && document.execCommand) {
    var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
    oWin.document.write("your text goes here");
    oWin.document.close();
    var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true)
    oWin.close();
    return false; //do NOT follow the link
}
```

The problem is the user HAS to provide the filename + the .csv or whatever other extension. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Although the question asked for certain IE compatibility, that wasn't in the question title, so I'm posting this solution for those who googled their way here. This is my solution that turns a table into a csv for client, giving a download button. Can probably be combined with Ustaman's solutions to make a a fullly cross-browser solution.

HTML:

```
<a download="report.csv" id="csvClick" href="#">Download CSV</a>
<table id="myTable">... </table>
<script>
makeCSV("csvClick", "myTable"); 
function makeCSV (link, targetTable) {
    var csvLink=document.getElementById(link);
    var dataurlHeader = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    var dataurlContent = "";

    var table = document.getElementById(targetTable);
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
       // row references rows
       if (i > 0){
           dataurlContent += "\n";
       }
       for (var j = 0, column; column = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         // column references columns
         if (j > 0) {
             dataurlContent += ",";
         }
         dataurlContent += column.innerHTML;
       }  
    }
    dataurlContent = encodeURIComponent(dataurlContent);
    csvLink.href = "" + dataurlHeader + dataurlContent;
}
</script>
```